# Windows 10 intermittently crashes while entering sleep mode—network driver issue or hardware failure?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bsod, network-adapter

I've been having intermittent problems with my Windows 10 (version 1703) system hanging while entering sleep mode. The machine turns off most hardware, but the disk activity indicator still flashes a bit. After a few minutes, the CPU fan revs up and the system powers off with one press of the power button, a telltale sign that the system has bugchecked (read: BSOD).

Here's a crash analysis:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.15063.468 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\100817-5062-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*E:\sysdebug\debug-symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*E:\sysdebug\debug-symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 15063 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`25e89000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`261d55c0
Debug session time: Sun Oct  8 01:06:20.821 2017 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 2:00:12.486
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
......................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
....................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 9F, {3, ffffdd0b4717d580, ffffb7805bbad8f0, ffffdd0b4f3bf8b0}

Probably caused by : pci.sys

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

4: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffdd0b4717d580, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffb7805bbad8f0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffdd0b4f3bf8b0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.15063.608 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

DUMP_TYPE:  2

DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0xc
  Insufficient Dumpfile Size
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffdd0b4717d580

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffb7805bbad8f0

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffdd0b4f3bf8b0

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  688dd739

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff804df0a0000 pci

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: a86

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DRAGON

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  10-08-2017 01:14:44.0333

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.15063.468 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffb780`5bbad8b8 fffff801`260acea7 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffdd0b`4717d580 ffffb780`5bbad8f0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffb780`5bbad8c0 fffff801`260acdb2 : ffffdd0b`4f265010 00000000`00000001 ffffb780`5bb80180 00000000`00000001 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xeb
ffffb780`5bbad920 fffff801`25efad48 : ffffdd0b`4f265048 ffffdd0b`4f265088 00000000`00000001 00000010`cafa28b9 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x22
ffffb780`5bbad970 fffff801`25efbbb7 : ffffb780`5bb80180 00000000`002823e3 00000000`0000065c 00000000`000432d6 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0x248
ffffb780`5bbada60 fffff801`25ff862a : 00000000`00000000 ffffb780`5bb80180 00000000`00000000 ffffb780`5bb8cd80 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x367
ffffb780`5bbadc60 00000000`00000000 : ffffb780`5bbae000 ffffb780`5bba8000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  418dcf5cc7a95525fe8ac8ffec7980c508fac304

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  aa7ded8050d69815c7ceb83e8c2568f590a49d74

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  ee8fcf1fb60cb6e3e2f60ddbed2ec02b5748a693

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.15058.0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Netwbw02_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Netwbw02_IMAGE_pci.sys

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Netwbw02_IMAGE_pci.sys

TARGET_TIME:  2017-10-08T05:06:20.000Z

OSBUILD:  15063

OSSERVICEPACK:  608

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2017-09-05 00:09:34

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160101.0800

BUILDLAB_STR:  WinBuild

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.15063.608

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  558

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_power_down_netwbw02_image_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {de9d41cd-e92a-1112-4b45-e9117c3424d2}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

4: kd> lmvm pci
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff804`df0a0000 fffff804`df0fb000   pci      # (pdb symbols)          e:\sysdebug\debug-symbols\pci.pdb\1C4946DF979E356EA9C0FF3CE9AE5ABF1\pci.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: pci.sys
    Mapped memory image file: e:\sysdebug\debug-symbols\pci.sys\688DD7395b000\pci.sys
    Image path: pci.sys
    Image name: pci.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Sat Aug  2 05:15:37 2025 (688DD739)
    CheckSum:         00063A5B
    ImageSize:        0005B000
    File version:     10.0.15058.0
    Product version:  10.0.15058.0
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     pci.sys
    OriginalFilename: pci.sys
    ProductVersion:   10.0.15058.0
    FileVersion:      10.0.15058.0 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
    FileDescription:  NT Plug and Play PCI Enumerator
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
4: kd> lmvm netwbw02
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff804`e2b70000 fffff804`e2efc000   Netwbw02   (deferred)             
    Image path: Netwbw02.sys
    Image name: Netwbw02.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Sun Oct  9 12:00:54 2016 (57FA69B6)
    CheckSum:         003607E7
    ImageSize:        0038C000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

Some further digging in Security and Maintenance found this hardware error:

[image: Security and Maintenance: hardware error]

Again, this only happens intermittently when I put the system to sleep.

The `Netwbw02` in `0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Netwbw02_IMAGE_pci.sys` points to some sort of wireless network adapter issue (this system uses an **Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260** network adapter). The network driver hasn't been recently updated and was working properly all along, and I'm not aware of any other recent changes to the system that could be causing this to occur. One thing of note that may be relevant is that the Wi-Fi occasionally stops working when I wake the system up from sleep, and I have to turn it off and back on.

Also, notice that the debugger indicates that the crash is in `pci.sys`, which is part of Windows. It's not in the network adapter driver `netwbw02.sys`. This is giving me the impression that it's a hardware problem, but I don't want to buy a new NIC unless I'm sure that this is the case.

Any idea what's going on? Should I try updating the Wi-Fi driver, or am I going to have to replace the network adapter?

---

#### Edit

Updated the Wi-Fi driver. Unfortunately, the crash still happens. I have a full memory crash dump on hand and will be taking a closer look.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.15063.468 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Full address space is available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*E:\sysdebug\debug-symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*E:\sysdebug\debug-symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 15063 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`02e9a000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`031e65c0
Debug session time: Sun Oct  8 09:23:53.258 2017 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:32:57.922
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
......................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
..............................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 9F, {3, ffffc48361d56780, ffff8381d352d8f0, ffffc483c3335010}

Implicit thread is now ffffc483`61145040
Probably caused by : tcpip.sys ( tcpip!FlpUninitializePacketProviderInterface+55 )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

3: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffc48361d56780, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffff8381d352d8f0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffc483c3335010, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

Implicit thread is now ffffc483`61145040

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 402

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Notebook                        

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  P15SM                           

SYSTEM_SKU:  Not Applicable                  

SYSTEM_VERSION:  Not Applicable                  

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  4.6.5

BIOS_DATE:  12/04/2013

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Notebook                        

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  P15SM                           

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Not Applicable                  

DUMP_TYPE:  0

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffc48361d56780

BUGCHECK_P3: ffff8381d352d8f0

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffc483c3335010

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

FAULTING_THREAD:  61145040

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: a86

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3c,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1E'00000000 (cache) 1E'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DRAGON

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  10-08-2017 09:28:00.0201

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.15063.468 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80102ecdf4a to fffff8010300b3b6

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff8381`d33f5cf0 fffff801`02ecdf4a : ffffc483`61145040 00000000`0009dc48 fffff801`0134b180 ffff8381`d33f5fc9 : nt!KiSwapContext+0x76
ffff8381`d33f5e30 fffff801`02ecd911 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 fffff80b`73626f0c : nt!KiSwapThread+0x16a
ffff8381`d33f5ee0 fffff801`02ecd228 : ffffc483`6b65ffe0 ffffc483`00000000 ffffde71`9a208800 ffff8381`d33f6088 : nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x101
ffff8381`d33f5f80 fffff801`02f95ab0 : ffff8381`d33f6088 ffffc483`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x2b8
ffff8381`d33f6050 fffff80b`738ba269 : ffffc483`c5fcbf20 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000000 ffffc483`6b6539d0 : nt!ExWaitForRundownProtectionReleaseCacheAware+0xa0
ffff8381`d33f60c0 fffff80b`7388f7e0 : 00000000`00000000 fffff80b`736a37d8 00000004`40430088 fffff801`02fa0e5a : tcpip!FlpUninitializePacketProviderInterface+0x55
ffff8381`d33f6100 fffff80b`736c64e8 : ffffffff`5f114500 ffffc483`64366940 ffffc483`6b0849f0 ffffc483`6b6539d0 : tcpip!FlPnpEvent+0x138
ffff8381`d33f61a0 fffff80b`737088b6 : 00000000`00041eb0 ffffc483`6b6539d0 00000000`00000008 00000000`c00000bb : ndis!ndisDeliverNetPnPEventSynchronously+0x18c
ffff8381`d33f6210 fffff80b`736c6329 : ffff8381`d33f6460 ffff8381`d33f64d9 ffff8381`d33f6460 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisPnPNotifyBinding+0xe2
ffff8381`d33f63f0 fffff80b`736cccbf : ffffc483`6b0849f0 fffff80b`736c4af9 ffff99cf`c2a1629c 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisPnPNotifyBindingUnlocked+0x35
ffff8381`d33f6440 fffff80b`736ccbe7 : ffff8381`d33f65b0 ffffb40f`48e72570 ffffc483`67dab1a0 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisPauseProtocolInner+0x7f
ffff8381`d33f6540 fffff80b`736c3b99 : ffffc483`67dac5b0 ffff8381`d33f6680 ffffc483`67dab1a0 00000000`00000001 : ndis!ndisPauseProtocol+0x63
ffff8381`d33f6580 fffff80b`736c39d0 : 00000000`00000000 ffffc483`67dac5b0 00000000`00000000 ffff8381`d33f6770 : ndis!Ndis::BindEngine::Iterate+0x17d
ffff8381`d33f66f0 fffff80b`736c3989 : ffffc483`67dac5b0 ffffc483`67dac5b0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ndis!Ndis::BindEngine::UpdateBindings+0x34
ffff8381`d33f6720 fffff80b`736c376c : ffffc483`67dac5b0 00000000`00000000 ffffc483`67dac548 fffff80b`736c38d6 : ndis!Ndis::BindEngine::DispatchPendingWork+0x69
ffff8381`d33f6750 fffff80b`73641a61 : ffffc483`67dab1a0 00000000`00000020 ffffc483`67dac5b0 ffffc483`67dac5b0 : ndis!Ndis::BindEngine::ApplyBindChanges+0x54
ffff8381`d33f67a0 fffff80b`736b89b1 : ffffc483`67dab1a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000004 ffffc483`61027e00 : ndis!ndisPrepForLowPower+0x20e2d
ffff8381`d33f6870 fffff80b`736b8869 : 00000000`00000000 ffffc483`c3335010 ffffc483`00000004 ffff8381`d33f6970 : ndis!ndisSetSystemPower+0x13d
ffff8381`d33f68f0 fffff80b`736317f8 : ffffc483`c3335010 ffffc483`61d4ca20 ffffc483`c3335170 ffffc483`686ad960 : ndis!ndisSetPower+0xa9
ffff8381`d33f6930 fffff80b`72c891fd : ffff8381`d33f6a80 ffff8381`d33f6a19 ffffc483`c3335010 ffffc483`686ad960 : ndis!ndisPowerDispatch+0x138
ffff8381`d33f6960 fffff80b`72c62e1b : ffffc483`686ac040 ffff8381`d33f6a80 ffff8381`d33f6a80 ffffc483`686ad960 : Wdf01000!FxPkgFdo::_PowerPassDown+0x6d [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\pnp\fdopower.cpp @ 85] 
ffff8381`d33f6990 fffff80b`72c5752e : 00000000`00000002 00003b7c`97951cd8 ffffc483`686ad960 00000000`00000000 : Wdf01000!FxPkgFdo::DispatchSystemSetPower+0x177 [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\pnp\fdopower.cpp @ 292] 
ffff8381`d33f69e0 fffff80b`72c56b95 : ffffc483`c3335010 ffffc483`686ae320 ffffc483`686ad960 fffff801`02ecd228 : Wdf01000!FxPkgPnp::Dispatch+0xee [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\pnp\fxpkgpnp.cpp @ 670] 
ffff8381`d33f6a80 fffff801`02fce795 : fffff801`031e1200 fffff801`00000000 ffffc483`c33350b8 ffffc483`61145040 : Wdf01000!FxDevice::DispatchWithLock+0x155 [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\core\fxdevice.cpp @ 1430] 
ffff8381`d33f6b70 fffff801`02f76f77 : ba40301c`1c304024 fffff801`02fce570 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000084 : nt!PopIrpWorker+0x225
ffff8381`d33f6c10 fffff801`0300ba06 : ffff8381`d3580180 ffffc483`61145040 fffff801`02f76f30 021e3233`023e3435 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x47
ffff8381`d33f6c60 00000000`00000000 : ffff8381`d33f7000 ffff8381`d33f1000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  .thread 0xffffc48361145040 ; kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  c6a4e3fd19a6d54b27c51b7e50dfa383f1eba183

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  d6dcc7d2f29fb3a58f934e1fe15e4fbba8b6a7d0

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  e66b551238e6d67fdb8eae4e16e8c40c6c344ac6

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
tcpip!FlpUninitializePacketProviderInterface+55
fffff80b`738ba269 4883c430        add     rsp,30h

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  30c48348

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  5

SYMBOL_NAME:  tcpip!FlpUninitializePacketProviderInterface+55

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: tcpip

IMAGE_NAME:  tcpip.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  ce73ded

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  55

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  OLD_IMAGE_tcpip.sys

BUCKET_ID:  OLD_IMAGE_tcpip.sys

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  OLD_IMAGE_tcpip.sys

TARGET_TIME:  2017-10-08T13:23:53.000Z

OSBUILD:  15063

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2017-09-05 00:09:34

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  170317-1834

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs2_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  52e

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:old_image_tcpip.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {37e54100-f2ed-64aa-46d2-171c94f44540}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

3: kd> lmvm tcpip
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff80b`73810000 fffff80b`73aaa000   tcpip      (pdb symbols)          e:\sysdebug\debug-symbols\tcpip.pdb\CDF1678E5F85E887DBB83616A2CF79B21\tcpip.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: tcpip.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tcpip.sys
    Image name: tcpip.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Wed Nov 10 08:41:01 1976 (0CE73DED)
    CheckSum:         00291A48
    ImageSize:        0029A000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

This time, the hardware error looks like this, which might be useful in debugging the problem:

> **Description**
> A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.
>
> **Problem signature**
> Problem Event Name: `LiveKernelEvent`
> Code: `1a1`
> Parameter 1: `ffffc4836d04e580`
> Parameter 2: `0`
> Parameter 3: `0`
> Parameter 4: `0`
> OS version: `10_0_15063`
> Service Pack: `0_0`
> Product: `256_1`
> OS Version: `10.0.15063.2.0.0.256.48`
> Locale ID: `1033`

---

#### Dump file download

The most recent minidump file is available [here](http://www.fierydragonlord.com/files/bsod-dumps/100817-5437-01.dmp).

Comment: no, the real cause is the Intel Wifi driver Netwbw02.sys, not the PCI.sys. so update the driver

Comment: share the real dmp file, not the text

Comment: @magicandre1981: http://www.fierydragonlord.com/files/bsod-dumps/100817-5437-01.dmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using !podev, !devstack and !irp commands still point to Intel WIfi driver

```
0: kd> !podev ffffde8943bbb060
Device object is for:
  DriverObject 43b8f4d0
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000022 AttachedDev ffffde8943bbbe40 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffde8943bbb7b8:
PowerFlags: 00000010 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=1
Dope: 00000000:
0: kd> !devstack ffffde8943bbbe40
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffde894a496c60  \Driver\vwifibus   ffffde894a497310  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffde894a496c30

  ffffde894ac10050 Unable to load image Netwbw02.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for Netwbw02.sys
 \Driver\NETwNb64   ffffde894ac101a0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffde894ac10020

> ffffde8943bbbe40  \Driver\ACPI       ffffde8943b7c770  
  ffffde8943bbb060  \Driver\pci        ffffde8943bbb1b0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffde8943bbbb30 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08B1&SUBSYS_40708086&REV_73\4&66f3703&0&00E3"
  ServiceName is "NETwNb64"

0: kd> !irp ffffde899be8faf0
Irp is active with 5 stacks 3 is current (= 0xffffde899be8fc50)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0  0 ffffde894ac10050 00000000 00000000-00000000    
           \Driver\NETwNb64
            Args: 00014400 00000000 00000004 00000002
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffde894a496c60 00000000 fffff802f1023e50-ffffde894488c010 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\vwifibus nt!PopSystemIrpCompletion
            Args: 00014400 00000000 00000004 00000002
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffde894488c010
```

The crash happens while changing power state to sleep:

```
0: kd> !poaction
PopAction: fffff802f0f631a0
  State..........: 3 - Set System State
  Updates........: 0 
  Action.........: Sleep
  Lightest State.: Sleeping3
  Flags..........: 80000004 OverrideApps|Critical
  Irp minor......: SetPower
  System State...: Sleeping3
  Hiber Context..: 0000000000000000
```

Try [this version 20.0.0.9](http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=353&func=startdown&id=3100&lang=en) from September 2017.

If this does't fix it, run devcon.exe to disable the Wifi adapter before going to sleep (start scheduled task of devcon with the Windows Power Event trigger for sleep).

If nothing helps, replace the Wifi adapter with a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Your wifi driver is significantly out of date (and it appears to be the culprit driver).

Download the latest version for Windows 10 from here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005634.html (19.70.0 as of the time of this writing)

Comment: Wi-Fi driver has been updated, no luck. See update.